# How to linck libname.so to C?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I have simple C-code and big libname.so, with libname.h of corse.
I tryed `gcc -L. -lurpcadc -o -I Ctest.c`, i did preliminarily `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/way/to/lib`, but i caught next errors:

```
/tmp/cc4jgpfg.o: In function `main':
Ctest.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `func_from_lib'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What i need to do?
It is too simple, but sometimes I have problems with this kind of thing.

Comment: Oh, i fogot, liburpcadc is real name of lib.

Comment: List the library contents. with nm.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc Ctest.c -I. -L. -lname -o Ctest`
Headings were searched in the wrong place.